# Debian Ubuntu Network Manager bug

Tags: linux, debian

There is this problem with Debian based destro's when using the network manager. This morning I installed a D-Link wireless network card DHCP confgured but it was failing to get an IP until I removed Network-manager, restart the network populated the interfaces file with if configuration and I ran dhclient wlan0 and it connected like a charm!! Anyone with real info why its behaves like this??????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many bugs in the `network-manager` package. The Debian BTS has a [list of all network-manager issues](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=network-manager;dist=unstable).

Comment: That settles it!

Comment: That doesn't mean you should give up on Network Manager; if everyone does that, then it will never improve.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is bug in NetworkManager. I have also faced lot of problems with NetworkManager specially on wired LANs. So I always disable it and using only network services. For wireless NetworkManager makes it easy to reconnect so is usually worth the trouble. Update to latest version of NetworkManager of your distro and that might help.